# La película inicia / La película se inicia

Tags: pronombres

Tengo una duda. Estaba haciendo algunos ejercicios de gramática y mi guía de estudio indica que la oración «La película inicia» es incorrecta, y que la correcta debería ser «La película **se** inicia». ¿Podría alguien confirmarlo y en ese caso indicarme alguna fuente para consultar la regla gramatical?

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La oración "La película inicia (en X momento) (con X escena)" no es correcta en español. Normalmente, diríamos:

- La película comienza / empieza (en X momento) (con X escena).

Según el [DLE](https://dle.rae.es/iniciar), el verbo "iniciar" es transitivo y solo es intransitivo y pronominal para indicar "tener comienzo", por ejemplo:

> 4. prnl. Dar comienzo. Fue allí donde se inició el incendio.

Esto es confirmado por [Fundéu](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/iniciar-iniciarse-comenzar-empezar/#:%7E:text=Tal%20como%20se%C3%B1ala%20el%20Diccionario,no%20solo%20intransitivo%3A%20algo%20inicia.), que a su vez cita el Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas:

> Tal como señala el Diccionario panhispánico de dudas, el verbo *iniciar* puede ser transitivo («El peso mexicano inicia la jornada con ligero avance») o intransitivo pronominal («La amplia programación navideña se inicia el viernes con el alumbrado»), pero **no solo intransitivo**: *algo inicia*.

Por lo tanto, debería decirse:

- La película **se** inicia (en X momento) (con X escena).

No obstante, la oración precedente no es natural en español y se desaconseja su uso, puesto que "iniciarse" se usa para referirse a hechos. Con el sustantivo "película", normalmente usaríamos "comenzar" o "empezar".

Comment: Solo para clarificar, la oración completa era: «La película inicia con el asesinato de una familia completa». Y para confirmar, ¿la regla es que el pronombre «se» antecede a los verbos transitivos?

Comment: El pronombre "se" puede anteceder a verbos transitivos con sentido pasivo o impersonal, y también a verbos intransitivos pronominales. La recomendación es buscar el verbo en el diccionario y verificar si es transitivo, intransitivo o intransitivo pronominal. En el caso de "iniciar", según el diccionario cuando es intransitivo solo es pronominal, por lo que la oración "La película inicia con el asesinato de una familia completa" es incorrecta.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración